# Solve $a_n = a_{n-1} + n$, $a_0 = 0$, using generative function

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I need to solve, per $n\geq 1$:
$$\begin{cases}
a_n = a_{n-1} + n\\
a_0 = 0
\end{cases}$$

I have found this:

$$
f(x) - xf(x)  = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

So:

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{C}{(1-x)^3}
$$

And:

\begin{cases}
A=0\\
-2A -B = 1\\
A+B+C = 0
\end{cases}

The error is here, I get $A=0$ so is not possibile, where is my error?

Comment: why not possible?

Comment: What's wrong with $A=0$? You get $B=-1$ and so $C=1$, which gives a representation of $f(x)$. You can then check in reverse that you got a correct partial fraction expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=0$ is correct.
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}
$$
So that
\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2} &= - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{n} (-x)^n
\\&=
- \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1) (-x)^n\\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^n
\\
\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} &=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-3}{n} (-x)^n
\\&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2} (-x)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2} x^n
\end{align}
and add
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[-(n+1)+\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}\right] x^n
\\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n+1)}{2} x^n
\end{align}

And therefore $a_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: I tought that all three were necessary. Now I should find $a_n$, right? so: $\binom{n+1}{1}(-1)^n + \binom{n+2}{2}(-1)^n$, right? Am I done?

Comment: solving the binomial? $(-1)^n\big((n+1) + \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}\big)$

Comment: Your $(-1)^n$ are wrong

Comment: a hint, please?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi Just clarifying your misconception: you *generally* need all of the $A,B,C$ (or more, perhaps, in other problems) to deal with *arbitrary* polynomials of degree at most $2$ in the numerator. But in special cases you may still have one or more of them being zero; a trivial case is when the original numerator was already zero!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, $a_n$ is simply the sum of the first $n$ positive integers, so it is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}= n+ \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$, whose generating function is $x\cdot (\frac{1}{1-x})' + \frac{1}{2}x^2\cdot (\frac{1}{1-x})''$.